# Mantener Alertas activas en js

Tags: javascript

Como puedo retener alertas en js?

Normalmente el navegador te pregunta:

```
Quieres volver a ver este tipo de mensajes?
```

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Ejemplo</title>
  <script>
    function mensaje() {
      alert('Este es el mensaje que me refiero. El que esta debajo de este mensaje');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="mensaje();">
  Ejemplo
</body>
</html>
```

Bien se pueden omitir o simplemente cerrar.

Mi objetivo es mantener las alertas hasta que se cumpla con la respuesta correcta sin opción a cerrar o cancelar la alerta.

Answer (score 1):

Pues no se puede, ya que es un tipo de seguridad que tiene los navegadores contra las conocidas paginas que te llenan de alertas para que te quedes en el sitio y no vuelvas atrás.

La pregunta es para que quieres hacer esto?

Que es lo que estas desarrollando?

Por que se puede hacer de otra forma las preguntas como un div que no deja de molestar hasta que contestes correctamente. Pero no para mantenerte en una pagina, por que eso depende del navegador.

Espero haber sido claro y orientado lo que quieres hacer. Saludos!